# How to pass api login key and transaction id in authorize.net sdk for iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using Authorize.net payment gate way for My android Application. Normally Authorize.net ask for username and password by prompting a login screen so I dont want user to type merchant details so I edited authorize.net sdk and typed password directly instead of prompting screen to user for username and password.
    Below I have posted the sdk code like I have did it

```
    NSMutableArray *AuthArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *authDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Transaction"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"responsecode"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"authcode"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"avsResultCode"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"cvvResultCode"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"CavvResultCode"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"transactionID"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"referenceTranscationID"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"transHash"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"testrequest"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"accountNumber"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"accounttype"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"message"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"code"];
    [authDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"description"];

    [AuthArr addObject:authDict];

            PlaceOrderOperation *orderOP=[[PlaceOrderOperation alloc] init];
            [orderOP setAuthenticationID:[[UserAuthenticationManager sharedManager] authenticationKey]];
            [orderOP setOrderArray:orderArray];
            [orderOP setAuthArray:AuthArr];
            [orderOP setUserRemark:instructionStr];
            [orderOP setTotaltax:lbTax.text];

            [orderOP setDelegate:self];
            [operationQueue addOperation:orderOP];
            [orderOP release];

            [activity startAnimating];
            [self.view addSubview:activity];
```

The problem is for website they use login key and transaction id Which they will get it from sandbox merchant account. If I give that login key and transaction id in the above code it says invalid credentials. If I give username and password directly in my code it works.

Comment: I was able to fix is issue by passing AppLoginId to "merchantAuthentication.name" and  AppTransactionKey to "merchantAuthentication.transactionKey" for example-----request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppLoginId"];
    
    request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.transactionKey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppTransactionKey"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix is issue by passing AppLoginId to "merchantAuthentication.name" and AppTransactionKey to "merchantAuthentication.transactionKey" for example-----request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppLoginId"]; request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.transactionKey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppTransactionKey"];